# Is there any known habit to performantly load Android ListViews?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-listview

**To basically explain the situation:**
I am planning on creating a school schedule app for students. My app is currently just a basic MainActivity which has a side drawer and if you click on an item, it inflates the selected Fragment. My question refers to the subject list I am currently working on. When clicking on the FAB in the "SubjectsFragment" Fragment, it opens an Activity in which you can add subjects. After a subject has been added, it is being displayed in the "SubjectsFragment" - so, pretty basic. I already have all the database logic down and have created a custom adapter. But these things are not even causing the problem.

**Now to my problem:**
When I open the Fragment, it lags for a really small amount of time while populating the ListView. Although it only takes a small amount of time, it surely is noticeable, which means, the UIThread is blocked for this time.
I have not found any different implementations than the one I currently am using and I wonder if there are other ways of populating a ListView. Using an AsyncTask would not make sense as the population of the ListView still happens on the UIThread.
Here is a small code snippet of my implementation:

```
mListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.subjectsListView);
ArrayList<Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();
subject = new Subject("A", "B", "C", "D");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { //for loop just to add 100 items
    subjectList.add(subject);
}
ListAdapterView adapter = new ListAdapterView(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_subjects_listitem, subjectList);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For the sake of understanding my problem, it's not necessary to know how my Adapter works, as this also happens with the preloaded adapters of Android Studio. In this code snippet, 100 items are added to the list. But sadly, the micro-lags are also happening with only 20 items.

Is there any better/different way of implementing this and not making it lag? Sorry if it sounds stupid but I am still very new to Android programming and always still learning.

Comment: @Zoe Oh, I apologize. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView is old way how to create list in Android. There is a better/faster way, [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). [Example 1](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview), [example 2](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Comment: I just tried this out and I'm stoked, thank you for helping me out. Even in debug mode, I can populate the RecyclerView with 500 items without experiencing lags. I really appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: Because, he creates items on demand, so if user scroll he will create more and more items for show.